# How to define a tree type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I wrote a tree like type as below:

```
type ReactNode = ReactChild | Array<ReactNode>
```

but editor told me that

> TS2456: type alias 'ReactNode' circularly references itself.

How to solve fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a problem with recursions in type aliases, as shortly explained in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11237):

> type aliases are not like interfaces. interfaces are named types,
>   where as type aliases are just aliases. internally as well they are
>   treated differently, the compiler aggressively flatten types aliases
>   to their declarations.

There's a longer discussion here: [allow recursive generic type aliases](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6230).

In your case, you can do something like:

```
interface ReactNodeArray extends Array<ReactNode> {}

type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactNodeArray;
```